# Clean Python installation: SSL nested asn1 error with urllib.request.urlopen on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, ssl, https

I am trying to run the following code on a Windows 10 machine with a clean installation of Python 3.8:

```
import urllib.request
print(len(urllib.request.urlopen('https://python.org').read()))
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "%FilePath%\run.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(len(urllib.request.urlopen('https://localhost').read()))
  File "%PythonPath%\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "%PythonPath%\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "%PythonPath%\urllib\request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "%PythonPath%\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "%PythonPath%\urllib\request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "%PythonPath%\urllib\request.py", line 1286, in do_open
    h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout, **http_conn_args)
  File "%PythonPath%\http\client.py", line 1369, in __init__
    context = ssl._create_default_https_context()
  File "%PythonPath%\ssl.py", line 750, in create_default_context
    context.load_default_certs(purpose)
  File "%PythonPath%\ssl.py", line 574, in load_default_certs
    self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
  File "%PythonPath%\ssl.py", line 566, in _load_windows_store_certs
    self.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs)
ssl.SSLError: nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:4067)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I first ran into this issue when trying to setup a jupyter notebook. The error appears every time I want to do anything HTTPS related on this machine. The URL itself does not matter. The same thing happens even for https://localhost/. I tried running this code specifically to see, whether a clean python installation would fix the issue, but it did not.

I have tried running the same code on other Windows 10 machines and it works without any issues. I have not run into any SSL or HTTPS issues with anything but Python. I have also tried running the code on other versions of Python, but I get the same error, even if the installation is completely fresh.

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4245 for possible causes.